# TreeViewDragDropTarget could not be found

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I am trying an example with the TreeViewDragDropTarget however I cannot find the control in the toolkit. I am using the latest version of the toolkit. How can i use this control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a reference to the System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit assembly. The type you are looking for is in the System.Windows.Controls namespace.

Comment: thanks jeff..i can see the DataGridDragDropTarget and the PanelDragDropTarget in my toolbox but not the treeviewdragdrop..is this control visible in your toolbox?

Comment: you should be able to add it using XAML regardless

Comment: After referencing, it is still not in toolbox, but I could use it through XAML. One problem is it is likely causing designer crash for all other pages.